# Setting up a debug/profiling environment for remote site

Tags: server, permissions, php, nginx

I'm having some issues with profiling a site that is loading slowly (close to 2 minutes). It is developed in PHP, Smarty and MySQL (using nginx as the web server), and I've been wanting to use Xdebug to profile it; but, there's some sort of misconfiguration on the remote server that doesn't allow me to connect to the debugging session from Netbeans, so I copied all the site's contents via FTP and am trying to debug locally, replicating the remote environment (Ubuntu, PHP, and Nginx) as best I can.

However, I seem to be running into permission issues (I have all the content under /home//public_html with all the files and folders under it having permissions set to 755 or even 777) after following countless guides, so I'm asking for advice on whether or not this is the best approach, or what I should do to make this as straightforward and effortless as possible.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with the latest (to date) PHP, MySQL and Nginx installed from apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, here's what I did to solve the issue I had:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data ~/public_html/
sudo chmod -R g+w ~/public_html/
```

Then, nginx was able to write to the public_html folder and problem solved! It might seem straightforward (and there are countless threads on StackOverflow referring to this particular solution), but somehow I hadn't seen it.